# Azure CDN redirect regexp

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I tried to configure a redirect rule on a CDN Standard Microsoft endpoint, and I would add the SAS token to all the requests forwarded to a specific URI but I couldn't add a redirect rule with regexp like "/test(.*)".

I noticed into the documentation that the regexp redirect are available only on Premium Verizon.

Is it possible to configure on CDN Standard Microsoft a regexp redirect?

Thanks,
Marcello

Answer (score 1):

We were solving the same problem and our solution was following.
Set URL Rewrite rule in Azure CDN like this:

```
Source pattern: /
Destination: /{url_path}?<your_sas_token>
Preserve unmatched path: No
```

Note that:

- we were rewriting all URLs (Source pattern: /)
- we knew for sure that input url doesn't contain query string (that is why we put **?** in Destination)
- we found {url_path} reference in Azure Front Door [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rule-set-server-variables) and gave it a try for Azure CDN.

Comment: hi this works fine but if we give any querystring in the cdn path, then it breaks

Comment: Thanks, I persisted with this thanks to your post. But I keep finding the raw {url_path} text is being sent in the request to blob storage and resulting in ContainerNotFound error. Does it still work? Thinking to use Edgio Premium instead.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Microsoft CDN Standard does not support a wild card regex redirect, as mentioned by you the option is only available on Azure CDN Premium from Verizon. Please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-sas-storage-support#option-2-hidden-cdn-sas-token-using-a-rewrite-rule) for any additional details.